# Too many AJAX responses

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making a simple AJAX request and logging the response in the JS console using the following code. It works absolutely fine, but the one thing bugging me is that it's throwing back 3 responses from the server (see attached image).

Can anyone shed any light as to why this is?

```
var xmlHttp = newXMLHttpObj();

function newXMLHttpObj(){
    var xml;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    } else{
        xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xml;
}

function ajaxHandler(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
        //handle response
        var response = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;
        console.log(response);
        var name = response.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.data;
        var age = response.getElementsByTagName("age")[0].firstChild.data;
        ajaxContent.innerHTML = "Name: " + name + "<br />Age: " + age;
    } else{
        setTimeout(ajaxHandler, 1000);
    }
}

function ajaxProcess(){
    var ajaxContent = document.getElementById("ajaxContent");
    ajaxContent.innerHTML = "loading";
    //check server is ready to comunicate
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "/js/test.php", true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ajaxHandler;
        xmlHttp.send("name=the chuff&age=26");
    } else{
        setTimeout(ajaxProcess, 1000); //restart ajaxProcess until ready to comunicate
    }
}
```

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: where are you calling the `ajaxProcess()` function?

Comment: it's on the body.onload event - in the HTML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because your flow looks as follows:

1. Request object is not initialized  and `xmlHttp.readyState == 0`
2. `ajaxHandler` is binded as handler to ready state change (no mater what will be the state)
3. Request is initialized and sent
4. Server connection established and `xmlHttp.readyState == 1`
5. Ready state changed and `ajaxHandler` is called
6. **Since `xmlHttp.readyState != 4` new `ajaxHandler` call is scheduled after 1s**
7. Request received and `xmlHttp.readyState == 2`
8. Ready state changed and `ajaxHandler` is called
9. **Since `xmlHttp.readyState != 4` new `ajaxHandler` call is scheduled after 1s**
10. Request is processed and `xmlHttp.readyState == 3`
11. Ready state changed and `ajaxHandler` is called
12. **Since `xmlHttp.readyState != 4` new `ajaxHandler` call is scheduled after 1s**
13. Request finished and response is ready, `xmlHttp.readyState == 4`
14. Response is written to the console for the first time
15. 1s is passed and scheduled `ajaxHandler` calls are invoked **3 more times!** and response is written to console 3 more times.

So, generally you should see response logged to console **4** times, but not all browsers pass through all ready states (for example there may be no separate ready state 3 and browser switches from 2 directly to 4) and that's why you log response 3 times.

if you would like to fix it, just do not reschedule `ajaxHandler`:

```
function ajaxHandler(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){
        //handle response
        flag = true;
        var response = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;
        console.log(response);
        var name = response.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.data;
        var age = response.getElementsByTagName("age")[0].firstChild.data;
        ajaxContent.innerHTML = "Name: " + name + "<br />Age: " + age;
    }
}
```

Finally it is much more easier and convenient to take some library like jQuery that will take care about all this staff. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense now. I'm aware that jQuery can handle all of this, but it's always nice to understand which wires go where in the background.